# python ElementTree xml: parsing fromstring vs building elements

Tags: python, xml

Given a large array of numbers where:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4 ...] => <tag attrib="1" />
                    <tag attrib="2" />
                    <tag attrib="3" />
                    <tag attrib="4" />
                    ...
```

Which is more efficient/fast:

a) building them from scratch using `Element("name", attributes)` and appending them to some root

or

b) `fromstring(str)` where str is the string representation of those tags in the example

Comment: I would guess `(a)`, as `(b)` parses the text back into an `Element` and then applies `(a)` to it to return your final result.

Comment: sorry if it wasn't very clear. All i have is that array of numbers and I want the Elements at the end. What b) was suggest of doing is iterating over the array, build the string '<tag attrib="'+1+'" />' ... for all the numbers and then pass that final string to be parsed

Comment: Yep. `b)` will end up building a string that will be parsed into into `Element`s, but `a)` will build the `Element`s directly. `a)` is one step shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated test:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, XML, tostring
from timeit import timeit

elist = [e for e in xrange(1000)]

def test_normal():
    eroot = Element('root')
    for e in elist:
        eroot.append(Element("tag", {"attrib" :"%s" %e}))

def test_list():
    eroot = Element('root')
    [eroot.append(Element("tag", {"attrib" :"%s" %e})) for e in elist]


print "etree: %.6f" %timeit(test_normal, number=1000)
print "l-cmp: %.6f" %timeit(test_list, number=1000)

from xml.etree.cElementTree import Element, XML, tostring, fromstring
#from lxml.etree import Element, XML, tostring

print "ctree: %.6f" %timeit(test_normal, number=1000)
print "c-cmp: %.6f" %timeit(test_list, number=1000)

def test_string():
    eroot = "<root>"
    tags = ['<tag attrib="%s" />' %e for e in elist]
    eroot += ' '.join(tags) + '</root>'
    tree = fromstring(eroot)

print "strng: %.6f" %timeit(test_string, number=1000)    


etree: 13.302093
l-cmp: 12.276725
ctree: 5.482961
c-cmp: 5.692758
strng: 6.578780
```

The cElementTree is the fastest version. So i would say: don't use the string [abomination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1107807)! ;-)

Comment: Did you try Subelement? It was minimal slower then append in my setup,  i just didn't include it here. list-comp just so nobody claims i did ignore it's performance gains. where did i forget fromstring? in test_list() ?

Comment: you forgot to call fromstring in the 3rd example. Don't use listcomp for side-effects.

Comment: I've removed mentioning of SubElement (it is not documented in the stdlib's docs). I don't know whether there is a performance difference.

Comment: 10 is not a large number (see the first sentence in the question). Try your benchmark with larger numbers. You could run time it as `python -mtimeit -s 'from m import test_list as f' 'f()'`

Comment: ihh, didnt look into the docs. im still using python 2.x mostly so i cant say if SubElement is gone in 3. but in 2.6 2.7 it's still there, but a little bit slower (but maybe it's just a fluke)

Comment: there's no change in magnitude between the different approaches, but the default of 10^6 takes ages for a quick&dirty orienntation ;-)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, but it proves that fromstring is incredibly fast if you don't actually call it. :)

Comment: ;-) ahhh you mean the b) from the OP! lol - i just ignored it totaly XD